# Regex to allow dot comma with atleast one numeric value

Tags: regex

I need my regex to check for at-least one numeric value, and it should allow dot(.) and comma(.) How can i achieve this?

Currently I am using the following regex,

```
   [\d.,]
```

This allows integer, dot(.), and comma(,) but does not check whether the string contains at-least one numeric value.

Comment: Can you give us some example strings which match and do not match?

Comment: is this a valid one? `4.,`

Comment: I am trying to do a currency validation, If user inputs 40 in a text box it should be displayed as $40.00,  and if he enters 4,000 it should be shown as $4,000.00

Comment: Input value          40                  40.50                   4,000.50


         Expected O/P    $40.00           $40.50                  $4,000.50

Comment: @Avinash 
It is invalid input, but if user gives input like
        4,000.23 this is valid

Answer (score 0):

It is the regex that will work:

```
(\d+[\.\,\d]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this:

```
^(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:.\d+)?)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^$  : Anchors, ensures the whole string matches
\d+ : number one or more times
?:  : Non-capturing group
*   : Zero or more times
?   : Mark group as optional
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/63pv4GI4pk)